# async.detect maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of objects such as: (however my real array is `13000` long)

```
var items = [
  {
    name: "cat",
    id: "1"
  },
  {
   name: "dog",
    id: "2" 
  }
];
```

I am trying to iterate over the objects until an object with `name` is found

however I get maximum call size exceeded when using this large array `(13000 size)`, if I use the array above I get no error.

async code:

```
function getItemIdByName(itemName, done) {
  async.detect(
    items,
    function hasItemName(item, cb) {
      return cb(null, item.name === itemName);
    },
    function(err, result) {

      if (err) {
        return done(new Error(err));
      }

      if (_.isUndefined(result)) {
        return done(new Error("Item not found"));
      }

      done(null, result);
    });
};

getItemIdByName('Dog', function foundItem(err, itemId) {
  console.log("got error", err);
  console.log("got item", itemId);
});
```

I get the correct output in the console

```
got error null
got item { id: 2, name: 'dog' }
```

however I also get RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

**How can I make this work with my large array of objects?**

Comment: ?? Why would you search a list with an asynchronous operation? And why would you use a flat list if you're doing lookups by key?

Comment: I want to use this for an api endpoint, unfortunately I cannot change the data structure

Comment: Why not just use `.find()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ["iteratee"](https://github.com/caolan/async#detectcoll-iteratee-callback) is synchronous, which is causing the stack exhaustion problem (basically, it's processing all the items in the same "tick", using the same stack frame).

If you want to test your code with a synchronous test setup, you can use [`async.ensureAsync()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#ensureasyncfn) to make sure that the iteratee becomes asynchronous:

```
async.detect(
  items,
  async.ensureAsync(function hasItemName(item, cb) {
    return cb(null, item.name === itemName);
  }),
  ...
);
```